# Can't Debug in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a having play with the Magic Mirror 2 using vs2017 to integrate onto my PI 3. As this is my first time with VS I can't seem to get debug to work when trying to run Magic Mirror UWP App.

[image: My output from clicking start on debug]

These are the instructions and app I'm using [GIT Hub Magic Mirror](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/magic-mirror-demo)

Instructions followed:

1. In Visual Studio, go to Solution explorer, click on package.appxmanifest > Application and set http://webreflections.azurewebsites.net/create as the start page
2. On the ribbon, change the target architecture to match that of your PC (e.g. x64)
3. Set the debugging target to "Local machine" (changing the architecture in step 2 probably did this for you)
4. Click play to start the app running on your local machine
5. Follow the prompts on the create experience to save a profile for yourself

If anyone can explain why the program won't run (debug) I'll be extremely happy.

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider using some alternative platform, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as a compiler,  `gdb` as a debugger, and perhaps even install & use some Linux distribution ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Wouldn't using GCC for UWP and JS-based application be impossible?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch thank you for the quick reply, No I didn't think of using GCC and gdb. I guess I read the instructions and didn't think outside the box lol. I'll have a look at those you've just suggested. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea (because I don't know what is Magic Mirror .... However, I feel sorry for those relying exclusively on non-standard proprietary software building tools. There are tied to their tool maker